# switch statement multi character constant

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm trying to convert this into a switch statement

```
if (codeSection == 281)
    cout << "bigamy";
else if (codeSection == 321  ||  codeSection == 322)
    cout << "selling illegal lottery tickets";
else if (codeSection == 383)
    cout << "selling rancid butter";
else if (codeSection == 598)
    cout << "wounding a bird in a public cemetery";
else
    cout << "some other crime";

// Actual switch statement
switch (codeSection)
{
    case '281':
        cout << "bigamy" << endl;
        break;

    case '321':
    case '322':
        cout << "selling illegal lottery tickets" << endl;
        break;

    case '383':
        cout << "selling rancid butter" << endl;
        break;

    case '598':
        cout << "wounding a bird in a public cemetery";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "some other crime"<< endl;

}
```

The compiler says switch statement multi character constant, and gives me a yellow warning but still compiles. My question is are the case supposed to be only in char form? like case '2'

Comment: You should probably know that a compiler **warning** is something that you should take under advisement, but isn't necessarily going to break anything. Many warnings can be turned off, in fact (not that they necessarily should). **Errors**, on the other hand, prevent your code from compiling or running correctly.

Answer (score 6):

```
case '281':
```

should be

```
case 281:
```

and similarly for the rest, otherwise the compiler "thinks" that you try to use a multi-character constant, which is not what you probably want.

A `case` doesn't have to be a `char`. In fact, it must be a constant expression of the same type as the type of condition after conversions and integral promotions, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch.

Comment: ...the reason being, enclosing something in single quotes specifies it as a character literal, while leaving them off in this case makes it an integer literal.

Comment: @JasonMc92 True, afaik multi-character constants are somehow discouraged, as their value is implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found [this article](http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/computers/languages/c_multi-char_const.html) on the topic.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Ha ha, funny, I was glancing at the same one :)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.

Comment: @JimmyHuang If the answer addresses your question you can accept it (in case there's no better one).